# How to get contacts' photo?

Tags: android, bitmap, photo, android-contacts

I need to get contact's photo. So I get the contact's id and ues the folowing function to get photo.

```
Log.i(MenuActivity.TAG, "START: getContactPhoto; PARAMETERS: id: " + String.valueOf(id));
Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);

Bitmap photo;
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, photoUri);

photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

return photo;
```

And this to set the photo to imageView

```
if (photo != null) {
        Log.d(MenuActivity.TAG, "Photo exists");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
} else {
        Log.e(MenuActivity.TAG, "No photo for contact " + name);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.defult_foto);
}
```

My logcat:

```
START: getContactPhoto; PARAMETERS: id: 148
Photo uri: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/148
No photo for contact Ivan
```

The way I get contact id:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,
};

String where =
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" +                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;

String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

String sortOrder = null;

ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, where, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        try {
            id = "no-id";

            birthday = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            // some code

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Days", "No birthday date!");
        }
    }
}
cursor.close();
```

But it sais that none of my contact has photo, but it has. I belive smth is wrong. Any ideas?

P.S I'm a bit noob in andrid yet so if it won't be very difficult be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sample code to fetch the thumbnails

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="58dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity code

```
package com.example.contactsdisplaypic;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Context mContext;
public SimpleCursorAdapter sca;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = this;

    new LoadContactsTask().execute();
}

class LoadContactsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,
        };

        String where =
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;

        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

        String sortOrder = null;

        ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, where, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
        String[] from = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID};
        // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
        // create simple cursor adapter
        sca =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, result, from, to,
                  CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        sca.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2 );
        // get reference to our spinner
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner1 );
        s.setAdapter(sca);

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, 
                    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "contact id " + sca.getCursor().getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new LoadPicturesTask().execute(sca.getCursor().getString(2));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

            }

        });
    }

}

private class LoadPicturesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap[]> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(String... contactId) {
        Bitmap[] array = new Bitmap[2];

        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                Long.parseLong(contactId[0]));

        // thumbnail
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
             new String[] {Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    array[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return array;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] result) {
        if (result != null) {
            ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img1.setImageBitmap(result[0]);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

}
```

I was able to fetch some contacts for whom birthday was stored and then the thumbnail was fetched for whom it was available.

Comment: Now I've got an error in `InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, photoUri);`. My app just stops

Comment: Can you post the logcat logs here? Also print the photoUri in the logs

Comment: I've added it to the question @iago

Comment: try with the modified answer, just out of curiosity, how do you get the contact id?

Comment: Just no photos. Again "No photo for contact...". I've added the way I get contact's id to the question. @iago

Comment: check the way to access contact id in the answer

Comment: It sais "Failed to read row 22, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 25 rows, 3 columns." @iago

Comment: Have you changed the projection? It has 4 columns right?

Comment: No sorry I forgot. But when I've added this line about CONTACT_ID I've got the old result (just null photo). And I don't need the line `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` any more so I can delete it right? So it has 3 colums about **name**, **birthday** and **id**. Am I wrong? @iago

Comment: I have put up the sample code which worked for me, so try with it and let me know

Comment: Success! I saw all my contacts and photos, where it was. Now I'll try to use this in my code @iago

Comment: **Success!!** Now everything is working OK! Thank you very much! @iago